# How to print React component correctly?

Tags: reactjs

I print component using **react-to-print**. This is work, but I have some problems:

**1.** How to print component when user click on button in other component? I try this, but it isn't work:

```
    import ReactToPrint from 'react-to-print';
    class ReportPage extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {      
       isPrint: false
      };
     ...
     }
    ...

    printTable() {
     this.setState({ isPrint: true });
    }

    render() {
     return (
      <div>
       <ReactToPrint
        trigger={() => this.state.isPrint === true}
        content={() => this.componentRef}
       />
       <main>
        ...
        <ComponentToPrint ref={el => (this.componentRef = el)} />
       </main>
       <Footer handlePrintTable={this.printTable}/>
     </div>
     );
     }
    }
```

**Footer**

```
class Footer extends Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <footer className='footer'>
        ...
         <a className='btn btn-raised btn_white btn_icon-action btn_icon-action_print' href='#' role='button'
          onClick={this.props.handlePrintTable}
         >
          PRINT
         </a>
      ...
     </footer>
   );
  }
}
```

**2.** Why the table header (from component which I print) became white? In fact it's gray
[and looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVzQt.png)

**CSS**

```
& .table {
    &__thead {
        & .table {
            &__th {
                vertical-align: middle;
                text-align: center;
                color: #fff;
                background-color: #6c757d;
                .selected{ background: blue;}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to answer a question about styles without seeing the styles

Comment: @AndyRay I added to post. please check

Answer (score 0):

In footer use the handle click method:

- step 1: `onClick={this.handleClick}`
- step 2:

use the following code:

```
 handleClick(){
    this.props.handlePrintTable(true);
}
```

- step 3:

now in the ReportPage:

```
printTable(value) {
     this.setState({ isPrint: value });
    }
```

Comment: What must be in trigger? I did  as you wrote, but in trigger I leave this.state.isPrint === true and got an error: **this.props.trigger is not a function**

Comment: may be syntax error wrte in trigger={() => {this.state.isPrint === true}} and another thing why are checking this.state.isPrint === true this condion. what will it do?

Comment: I need click on the button and print the component. Button in Footer, component called from Report Page
I tried to change state in ReportPage (this.state.isPrint) and check it in trigger. But I don't understand how this trigger should work. 
In documentation I see example:  trigger={() => <a href="#">Print this out!</a>}. It's work, but it add link on top of page

Comment: if you want to print the page only then try window.print() that's the easy way. use onClick={window.print()}. sry my bad i didn't read the react-to-print.

Comment: I know about window.print, but I need to print only one component, not all page :)